# Add more then 2 string in Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So this is how my `Dictionary` looks like:

```
var questions: [String : String] = [
    "Question1" : "Answer1",
    "Question2" : "Answer2",
    "Question3" : "Answer3",
    "Question4" : "Answer4",
    "Question5" : "Answer5"
]
```

I am random choosing question and same answer like this:

```
@IBAction func newQuestionButton(_ sender: Any) {

        guard currentQuestionIndex != questions.count else {

            return
        }

        // This will give you the Question (and Key)
        let question = randomQuestions[currentQuestionIndex]

        // Use the Key to extract out the answer (value) from the Dictionary
        let answer = questions[question] ?? ""

        // Update your labels
        questionLabel.text = question
        answerLabel.text = answer

        // Increment your question index
        currentQuestionIndex += 1

    }
```

How can I change so I also have a category added to the "questions"? Something like: `"Food" : "Question1" : "Answer1",` .

Comment: best way is to use Struct instead of dictionary ...

Comment: @jawadAli How tho? Do I need to display in using a loop?

Answer (score 2):

Better use enum and structures:

```
enum Category{
    case drink
    case food
}
struct QuestionBlock: Comparable{
    let question: String
    let answer: String

    static func < (lhs: QuestionBlock, rhs: QuestionBlock) -> Bool {
        return lhs.question < rhs.question
    }
}
```

Both may be gathered together as:

```
var questions: [Category: [QuestionBlock]] = [
    .drink: [QuestionBlock(question: "Question1", answer: "Answer1"),
             QuestionBlock(question: "Question2", answer: "Answer2")],
    .food: [QuestionBlock(question: "FoodQuestion1", answer: "FoodAnswer1"),
            QuestionBlock(question: "FoodQuestion1", answer: "FoodAnswer1")]
    ]
```

usage:

```
var counter: [Category: Int] = [.food: 0, .drink: 0]

func getNewQuestion(type: Category) -> (question: String, answer: String)? {
    guard let questionsArray = questions[type]?.sorted(by: <) else {
        return nil
    }
    guard (counter[type] ?? 0) < questionsArray.count else {
        return nil
    }
    let element = questionsArray[counter[type] ?? 0]
    counter[type] = 1 + (counter[type] ?? 0)
    return (question: element.question, answer: element.answer)
}
```

So, in `newQuestionButton` just call function `getNewQuestion`, and check result on nil. I made different counters for each category

There is other way - to do one array, and sort it by question number:

```
 struct QuestionBlock: Comparable{
    let type: String
    let question: String
    let questionNumber: Int
    let answer: String

    static func < (lhs: ViewController.QuestionBlock, rhs: ViewController.QuestionBlock) -> Bool {
        return lhs.questionNumber < rhs.questionNumber
    }
}
```

You can set or even change questions array:

```
var questions: [QuestionBlock] = [
    QuestionBlock(type: "food", question: "Question1", questionNumber: 1, answer: "Answer1"),
    QuestionBlock(type: "food", question: "Question2", questionNumber: 2, answer: "Answer2"),
    QuestionBlock(type: "animal", question: "Question3", questionNumber: 3, answer: "Answer3"),

]
var counter: Int = 0
```

and checking will be similar (here counter will be integer and global for all types):

```
func getNewQuestion(type: String) -> (question: String, answer: String)? {
    let questionsArray = questions.filter({$0.type == type}).sorted(by: <)
    guard counter < questionsArray.count else {
        return nil
    }
    let element = questionsArray[counter]
    counter += 1
    return (question: element.question, answer: element.answer)
}
```

Comment: By the way, instead of using `let question = randomQuestions[currentQuestionIndex]` it is better to use
`let question = randomQuestions.dropFirst(currentQuestionIndex).first` and check on nil